# Stabdar led light fixture that has 14 gauge wire on a 20 amp circuit?

Tags: wiring, led, gauge

Can I install an led light fixture that has 14 gauge wire on a 20 amp circuit?

Comment: Or this? [Can I use 18g cord for one light bulb?](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/144820/can-i-use-18g-cord-for-one-light-bulb)

Comment: Or this? [Can I connect 12 gauge wire to 18 gauge wire for an outdoor light post and plug?](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/171477/can-i-connect-12-gauge-wire-to-18-gauge-wire-for-an-outdoor-light-post-and-plug)

Answer (score 0):

Fixture wiring (built in - attached to the fixture) can be whatever UL or ETL or another Nationally Recognized Testing Laboratory approved when the fixture was listed. If the fixture was not listed by an actual NRTL such as UL or ETL then you should not use the fixture at all, and should return it to where you bought it.

16 AWG and even 18 AWG are not uncommon. The building wiring TO the fixture must be 12AWG for a 20A circuit. So 14 AWG built into the fixture is fine. They have different rules than house wiring to the fixture.

Answer (score 0):

If the wire comes attached from the maker then it is okay, if the fixture has UL/CSA listing.

A CE listing/label is not legal/recognized  in North America.

As a person who is doing wiring inside of walls, you would need to obey code and only use the minimum 12(or larger) gauge wire on a 20 amp circuit, or reduce the breaker to a 15 amp rating, if 14 gauge wire was used or found.

Answer (score 0):

If the fixture came like that, out of the box and it is UL approved, it's OK to use. It very common to see smaller wire used when manufacturing light fixtures.